# how should be pom.xml to filter resources on WEB-INF?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am working on a Maven project. After making some changes on the pom.xml file, I compile it succesfully and when I deploy it in the jboss the deployment fails.
Before I made the changes, I was able to deploy it.

I have ENV profile defined. This is part of my pom.xml file:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/main/filters/filter-${env}.properties</filter>
            </filters>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>WebContent/WEB-INF</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>WebContent/WEB-INF</directory>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Am I doing something wrong with the pom.xml file?

Comment: how is your deployment failing? what did you change? do you have `env` defined? You shouldn't really define the same resource twice.

Comment: Well. Finally I decide avoid the problem.
The thing is <filtering> tag was corrupting some files so I decide to use other alternative.

Comment: Would you explain how it was corrupting and what alternative did you decide on?

Comment: Well, first of all I created just one profile instead of two. My only profile is PROD.
If I don´t use the Prod profile to compile the code, the compilation will be, by default, in DEV. 

In my pom.xml file, I configured the prod profile to replace the file that contains the urls and connection properties with database, etc. So when I compile the code in prod profile, the WAR file generated is constructed with the production file.